# EF Core open SQLite database generated from Azure MobileService

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, entity-framework-core

I need to read a SQLite database which is synced from Azure SQL with MobileService. The problem is, in MobileService, it saves DateTime type as unixepoch, a double value, not in format of YYYY:MM:DD hh:mm:ss.

So when EF Core accesses this column, it will throw an exception for wrong year, month, day format. I tried to use a `ValueConverter` in `OnModelBuilder`, but that's not helpful, exception happens before entering that function.

My question is, in EF Core, is there a way to specify the DateTime format as unixepoch, or is there a chance to do the conversion manually?

Comment: What is your EF model? Do you use any attributes?
I believe your C# field is datetime, but unixepoch is converted into byte[]

Comment: I check Azure MobileService source code, it define DateTime as Decimal (double or int), but TimeSpan forms as hh:mm:ss, so the DateTime stored as unixepoch.  While in the EF model, the C# code, yes, the field is DateTime. When it read a decimal type, it thrown exception.